# How should i understand the with of a n-to-1 multiplexor?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, circuit

I've been confused by the concept of the multiplexor.I just want to know what the the structure of 32 bits n-to-1 multiplexor is.

Answer (score 1):

A 32 bits n-to-1 multiplexer is a circuit with n inputs of 32 bits, one output and a selector. In the output you only have one of the input according to the selector value. Besides, as the inputs are 32 bits, the output is 32 bits too, that is identical to the selected input.